# Attempt to authenticate with O365 (and store credentials) 3 times then quit

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to store/retrieve a user's O365 credentials using the following function:

```
function Access-Credentials {    
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Management.Automation.PSCredential])]

    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]
        $App,

        [Switch]
        $Change
    )

    $App = Truncate-Filename -Filename $App
    $Filename = $PSScriptRoot + "\SecCred-" + $App + ".bin"

    # If we need to change the credentials, or if the current application's credentials don't exist, create
    If( $Change -or ((Test-PathEx -Path $Filename) -ne $True) ) {
        Try {
            Get-Credential | Export-CliXml -Path $Filename    
        }
        Catch [Exception] {
            Write-Log -err -text "Fatal error, unable to create credentials XML file: $Filename. Ran into error: $PSItem. Exiting..."
            exit
        }
    }

    return Import-CliXml -Path $Filename
}
```

This gets called on the following line in my script:

```
$Cred = Access-Credentials -App "OWA Signatures"  #Credentials are now stored against a file called "SecCred-OWASignatures.bin" so don't need to be authenticated in future
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $Cred -Authentication Basic –AllowRedirection -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
```

Basically, if the credentials already exist, proceed - otherwise, request them and store them.

This works OK. What I'd like to do now is...

- a) test if the credentials have **authenticated successfully**
- b) if they haven't, allow the user to attempt to **re-enter their credentials three times**
- c) if credentials are already stored, check them. if they don't authenticate, **prompt the user to enter new credentials**

I'm not really sure where to begin with this. I've attempted a while loop with an `$attempts` counter, but this appears to have done nothing - it simply repeatedly requests credentials.

```
$attempts = 0
While ( (-not($Session)) -or ($attempts -eq 3) ) {
    Write-Log -warn -text "The credentials provided have not authenticated. Please try again..."
    $Cred = Access-Credentials -Change -App "OWA Signatures"  #Credentials are now stored against a file called "SecCred-OWASignatures.bin" so don't need to be authenticated in future
    $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $Cred -Authentication Basic –AllowRedirection -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null

    #Increment the attempts counter
    $attempts++
}

If( ($attempts -eq 3) -and (-not($Session)) ) {
    Write-Log -err -text "Fatal error: unable to authenticate with O365 after three attempts. Please try different credentials."
    exit
}
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Is the purpose of the 3-try verification to ensure the password is entered correctly? If so, then I could recommend a different approach.

Comment: Sorry @Bill_Stewart, yeah, that's all I'm looking for - 3 attempts to enter a correct password.

Comment: See my answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809012/) for how to compare two `SecureString` objects safely without decrypting them.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart sorry, I may be being a bit thick, but I can't fully grasp how that helps my current predicament. Can you give me a brief psuedo answer to indicate how you'd use your function in this context?

Comment: Prompt for two different `SecureString` objects, then use the function to compare them to make sure the entries match. If they match, then you can attempt to authenticate.